# evaluation of $\int\frac{x^2}{\left(1+x^4\right)\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle \int\frac{x^2}{\left(1+x^4\right)\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x^2}{\left(1+x^4\right)\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\left(x^2+1\right)+(x^2-1)}{\left(1+x^4\right)\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$

Now Let $\displaystyle J = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(x^2+1)}{\left(1+x^4\right)\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$ and $\displaystyle K = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(x^2-1)}{\left(1+x^4\right)\sqrt{1+x^4}}dx$

But I did not understand how can i can i solve it

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: This is a tough integral, for an elementary calculus class. Are you sure the numerator isn't suppose to be $x^3$?

Comment: If you are looking for an elementary solution - there isn't one due to: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_theorem_on_the_integration_of_binomial_differentials

Comment: Yes actually it is $x^2$.

Comment: This is pretty tough, indeed. [Take a look.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28%28x^2%2F[%281%2Bx^4%29%281%2Bx^4%29^%281%2F2%29]%29dx%29) It involves elliptic integrals of the first and second kind, and the inverse hyperbolic sin function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2(1+x^4)^{-3/2}=f(-x)$. We have to find $F(x)$ such that $\int f(x)\text{d}x=F(x)+C$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$, being $C$ an arbitrary constant.

For $\theta>0$, let be $I(\theta)$ the integral $I(\theta)=\int_0^\theta f(x)\text{d}x$; putting $\frac{1}{1+x^4}=t$ the integral can be written as
$$
I(\theta)=\int_0^\theta x^2(1+x^4)^{-3/2}\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{4}\int_1^{\frac{1}{1+\theta^4}}(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\,t^{-\frac{1}{4}}\text{d}t
$$
and since $\theta>0$, $0<\frac{1}{1+\theta^4}<1$, we may write
$$
I(\theta)=-\frac{1}{4}\int_1^{\frac{1}{1+\theta^4}}(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\,t^{-\frac{1}{4}}\text{d}t=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 (1-t)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\,t^{-\frac{1}{4}}\text{d}t-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\frac{1}{1+\theta^4}}(1-t)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\,t^{-\frac{1}{4}}\text{d}t
$$
and using the Beta function $B(p,q)$ (see http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12) and the Incomplete Beta Function $B_\xi(p,q)$ (see http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.17)
$$
I(\theta)=\frac{1}{4}\left[B\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right) -B_{\frac{1}{1+\theta^4}} \left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]=\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{2\sqrt\pi}-\frac{1}{4}B_{\frac{1}{1+\theta^4}} \left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right).
$$
So it is evident that the integral is $\int f(x)\text{d}x=F(x)+C$ with 
$$
F(x)=-\frac{1}{4}B_{\frac{1}{1+x^4}} \left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right).
$$